# antlr grun hang indefinetly in windows command

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I ran  "`grun antlr.Expr prog test\test0.txt -gui &`" in **cmd** (Windows)" its just got hung over there so I terminated the job and ran "`grun antlr.Expr prog test\test0.txt test\tree.txt -tree`" but result is the same.

Grammar:

[image]

Test case:

[image]

Directory Structure:

[image]

Comment: @bartkiers It shouldn't try to read from stdin when you give it a file name as an argument though, no?

Comment: @sepp2k ah, yes, I thought TestRig always worked with user input from stdin, but providing a file also works I just saw.

Comment: @AbhishekMeshram I never use TestRig, but you might try to execute the command in the same folder as the grammar. I don't think `grun antlr.Expr ...` is coorect. On the ANTLR homepage it says `grun Expr ...`

Comment: @BartKiers `packagename.GrammarName` is correct. The homepage uses `grun Expr` because the grammar isn't in a package in the example. Given the `package antlr;` in OP's code, `antlr.Expr` should work. That said, I wouldn't recommend using `antlr` as the package name. Anyway, if `grun` were unable to find the classes, there'd be an error message to that effect. As far as I'm aware the only way that nothing would be happening would be either an actual infinite loop or `grun` waiting for input as you suspected, but I don't see why either be the case here.

Comment: @AbhishekMeshram Can you tell us how your `grun` is set up? Is it an alias or a script and what are its contents? The only thing I can think of is that you have a somehow messed up shell script that doesn't pass along the file name to the `TestRig` class. On an unrelated note: In the future, when posting your grammar or other code, please copy and paste it as text rather than posting an image. I can't copy the contents of an image into a file for testing like I can with text.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the package name either (obviously). Thanks for the info @sepp2k!

Comment: @BartKiers grun is a batch file "java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*"

Comment: grammar Expr;

/* the grammar name and file must match */

@header {
 package antlr;
}

//Start variable
prog: (decl | expr)+ EOF
 ;
 
decl: ID ':' INT_TYPE '=' NUM
 ;

/* ANTLR resolves ambiguities in favor of the alternative given first. */
expr: expr '*' expr 
 | expr '+' expr
 | ID
 | NUM
 ;
 
/* Tokens. */
ID : [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*; //identifiers
NUM : '0' | '-'?[1-9[0-9]*;
INT_TYPE : 'INT';
COMMENT : '--' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip;

Comment: i: INT = 5
 i: INT = 7
j = i +23 : INT
24 * k
   i: INT = 9

Comment: I had a similar problem which turned out to be that, like @sepp2k said above, it was waiting for input. After I provide input and ctl-z to terminate the grun returned the output I was waiting for.